# Php/mysql ranking system - Placement inside a result set ordered by column

Tags: php, mysql

In a blog-like website, all the users can "star" a news (= bookmark it, mark it as "favourite").
I have a mysql table for stats.

```
table_news_stats

id_news
total_stars (int) //Total number of users who starred this news
placement (int)
```

The `placement` field is intuitive: if you order all the news by the `total_stars` field you get each news `placement`. So, the news with most stars will be number `1`, and so on.

So, suppose I have 700 records in my `table_news_stats`, and for each one I have the `id` and the `total_stars` count, how can I update the `placement` field automatically for each record? Which query is faster/better?

Example of the table_news_stats content:

```
First record (A):
1-3654-?

Second record (B):
2-2456-?

Third record (C):
3-8654-?
```

If you order the record by stars count:
the sequence of records is C - A - B

So... the result will be:

```
First record (A):
1-3654-2

Second record (B):
2-2456-3

Third record (C):
3-8654-1
```

**Clarification:**
why would I ever need the `placement` field at all?
It's pretty simple... the placement field will be populated by a cronjob the first day of every month. Basically it will provide a 'snapshot' of the rank of each news in terms of popularity (as it was at the beginning of the current month). As a consequence, thanks to the placement field, I will have the following information:

```
"The 1st day of this month the 'top starred' news list was like this:  
1- News C  
2- NewsA  
3- News B "
```

Then, with a query "SELECT * FROM table_news_stats ORDER BY total_stars DESC" I can obtain the new ranking (in real-time).

As a consequence, I will have the following information:

```
"At the time the page is loaded, the 'top starred' news list is like this:  
1- News A  
2- News C  
3- News B "
```

Finally, by comparing the two rankings, I obtain the last piece of information:

```
"News A has gained a position" +1
"News C has lost a position" -1
"News B has no change in position" +0
```

If there is a better way of doing this, let me know.

Comment: So you want to update which table the `table_news_stats` or the other table ?

Comment: I want to update the placement field in table_news_stats

Comment: Hmm could you please provide some sample example, and what would happen after update, I still did not quite understand it.

Comment: Why you need the field placement if the value in it is the same as of total starts you directly sort on that total starts asc on the column @IgorCarmagna

Comment: I feared you would think that. I updated the question with a clear explanation... It's very quick to read and I promise it is really interesting. Please let me know what you think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you don't need to `update` the table just:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_news_stats
ORDER BY total_stars DESC
```

But if you want to know the place of each one you can:

```
SELECT *, IF(@idx IS NULL,@idx:= 1,@idx:= @idx+1) 
FROM table_news_stats
ORDER BY total_stars DESC
```

And if you still need to `update` something like:

```
UPDATE table_news_stats 
SET placement = FIND_IN_SET(id_news,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.id_news) FROM (SELECT id_news
    FROM table_news_stats 
    ORDER BY total_stars DESC) t ))
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa82d/1)

Comment: I added a clarification in my question... It's very quick... please let me know what you think. Is your solution still right?

Comment: Sure my solution is still correct. Incorrect is your question :-)

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say that :-)

Comment: I saw the fiddle... really great. Thank you very much. I just have two questions: 1- Why is placement field = 1 for every record? Where does that value come from? 2- How can I update placment field with idx value?

Comment: This is very very gooood. Basically the answer to the question lies in the UPDATE query of your fiddle (the one with find_in_set function). The last SELECT query is useful to obtain the live ranking (real-time)... basically it evaluates the placement on-the-fly without actually changing the database placement value. This way I can compare the real-time placement with the 'last month' placement stored in the database. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, sure you can get both *stored* and *current* rank using that last select

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much. I'm sure this question/answer will help many other people. P.s. A great fiddle for a great answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+-------------+-----------+
| id   | total_stars | placement |
+------+-------------+-----------+
|    1 |           3 |         0 |
|    2 |           6 |         0 |
|    3 |           7 |         0 |
|    4 |           2 |         0 |
|    5 |           9 |         0 |
|    6 |           2 |         0 |
|    7 |           1 |         0 |
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now using the following you can update the `placement` as

```
update test t1 join
(
 select *,
 @rn:= if(@prev = total_stars,@rn,@rn+1) as rank ,
 @prev:= total_stars
 from test,(select @rn:=0,@prev:=0)r 
 order by total_stars desc
)t2
on t2.id = t1.id
set t1.placement = t2.rank ;


mysql> select * from test order by placement ;
+------+-------------+-----------+
| id   | total_stars | placement |
+------+-------------+-----------+
|    5 |           9 |         1 |
|    3 |           7 |         2 |
|    2 |           6 |         3 |
|    1 |           3 |         4 |
|    4 |           2 |         5 |
|    6 |           2 |         5 |
|    7 |           1 |         6 |
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

Note that in case of tie will have the same placement.

Comment: I added a clarification in my question... It's very quick... please let me know what you think. Is your solution still valid?

Comment: Ah I see , well in that case the cronjob is a better idea to deal with this. My solution is to update the data at once, however you can apply the above query 1st of every month to have the placement value. But the issue is its not going to give you the rank changes, however you will need a association table to keep track of rank changes. If you look at the http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2015-04-01/1039843#1039843 it does almost same thing

Comment: Mmm.. wait... my idea was to let the 'total_stars' field change freely every time a user bookmarks a specific news. Very simple... update the count by +1 or -1 as needed. Then the first day of every month a cronjob does a snapshot and populates the 'placement' field. Nothing more. Finally, each time a user loads the webpage with the live rankings, the page will perform a query to obtain the real-time ranking (by total_stars field). While echoing the first 50 records of the result set, I will compare their placement to the old one (saved in the placement field)

Comment: I saw the link just now... yes... that is what I'm trying to do. One last thing... what did you mean by 'you will need a association table to keep track of rank changes.'? Is there another (better) solution than the one presented above?

Comment: Ok say every month/week you re-calculate the rank, so you may need another table to store the previous rank data in a history table so that you get the difference of rank. What you can do is to create a table, now first time when you create the rank you insert all the ranks in that table as well keep a column in the table as `id`,`new_rank`,`old_rank`. For the first time `old_rank` will be `0`, next time you first update the table with `old_rank` column and then update the `new_rank` with the latest rank, so that you have the rank difference.